# What data is actually in the Oracle userenv context variable "authentication_data"?

Tags: java, oracle, ssl

Our customers connect to our databases exclusively with jdbc thin client calls on the SSL port, authenticating externally with PKI certificates in keystores.  I would like to collect some of their client certificate information at logon time, as I would be able to do using OWA_UTIL.GET_CGI_ENV if they were connecting via https.

I've researched this for quite a while now, and I've found something in the SYS_CONTEXT userenv parameters called AUTHENTICATION_DATA that seems promising.  However, the documentation states only that for users connecting externally with x503 certificates (do they mean x509v3?), that parameter contains "Data being used to authenticate the login user. For X.503 sessions, returns the context of the certificate in HEX2 format."

That's all Oracle has to say about that.  No documentation of "HEX2 format" exists.  No explanation anywhere about how to view the authentication data.

Does anyone have any experience using that data or at least reading what it really is?